# Detecting signal / amplitude from 2 wire DC speaker

Tags: microcontroller, audio, signal, detection

I want to create a circuit that replaces a 2 wire speaker in an existing electronic device. I want the device to be able to trigger an output when the amplitude of the signal that would regularly going to the speaker, exceeds a certain level. The device with the speaker is a small USB powered toy, so voltages shouldn't be very high.

If anyone could give me some pointers on how to achieve this with analog circuitry and or a microcontroller, that would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you need a peak detector circuit. This can be as simple as a single diode and a capacitor. There's a very good video lecture over on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jllsqRWhjGM) which discusses how it works and various forms of the circuit depending on what you want to achieve.